# what a correct statement for this code?

Tags: php, drupal-6

I want print $str_agunan that returned from statement. i make statement that all values can be true, so i use operator .= but on webview its showing string from rows before. thanks advance, sorry if my english is bad.

```
$agunan = db_query("SELECT * FROM pengajuan_agunan where cif_nokode = '".$baris->no_kode."'");
        $cnt_agunan = db_result(db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pengajuan_agunan WHERE cif_nokode = '" . $baris->no_kode. "'"));

        if($cnt_agunan > 0) {
            while ($data_agunan = db_fetch_array($agunan)) {

                if ($data_agunan['jenis_agunan'] == 1 && !empty($data_agunan['kend_no_bpkb'])) {

                    $str_agunan .= "Jenis agunan kendaraan dengan no. BPKB " . $data_agunan['kend_no_bpkb'] . ", ";

                }

                if ($data_agunan['jenis_agunan'] == 2 && !empty($data_agunan['shm_no'])) {

                    $str_agunan .= "Jenis agunan sertifikat dengan no. SHM " . $data_agunan['shm_no'] . ", ";

                }

                if ($data_agunan['jenis_agunan'] == 3 && !empty($data_agunan['karyawan_nama'])) {

                    $str_agunan .= "Jenis agunan karyawan dengan nama karyawan " . $data_agunan['karyawan_nama'] . ", ";

                }

                if ($data_agunan['jenis_agunan'] == 4 && !empty($data_agunan['sph_no'])) {

                    $str_agunan .= "Jenis agunan SPH dengan no. SPH " . $data_agunan['sph_no'] . ", ";
                } 
            }
        }else{
            $str_agunan = 'Data agunan belum diisi.';
        }
print_r($str_agunan);
```

[image]

Comment: should not be possible to get more than one `$str_agunan` string as the if statements are mutually exclusive

Comment: i updated the picture when more than one (if statement) becomes true

Comment: ty, i've solve this.